# Postgres trigger check amount before delete

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I am trying to create a postgres before trigger to check the amount of records that are going to be deleted before it actually does. For example to not delete more than 5 records

Comment: Why not do this in the `delete` statement itself?

Comment: I want to use it as a safety feature. So that you don't have to build these checks in the apps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve that with an AFTER DELETE statement-level trigger. Inside the trigger function you can count the number of affected rows and throw an exception if the count is too high. The exception will force a rollback of the transaction that initiated the delete.

```
create function prevent_delete()
  returns trigger
as
$BODY$ 
declare
  l_count integer;
begin 
  select count(*)
    into l_count
  from old_table;

  if l_count > 5 then 
    raise exception 'Too many rows would be deleted';
  end if; 
  return null;
end; 
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And then create the trigger:

```
create trigger prevent_mass_delete 
   after delete on the_table
   referencing old table as old_table
   for each statement 
   execute procedure prevent_delete();
```

Comment: Just curious: Why aren't you building the same function as BEFORE DELETE trigger?

Comment: @S-Man: because statement level triggers can only be defined as AFTER triggers (which makes sense, because only _after_ everything was done can the database know which rows were affected by the statement)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will this revert the deleted records though?

Comment: @AndreCoetzee: yes, as I wrote: it will rollback the transaction.